# How to put JDesktopPane in background in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdesktoppane

i'm developing a java application in which i have a JFrame with a `JDesktopPane` in full screen size. My problem is that `JDesktopPane` cover the `JButton(s)` inside the JFrame so i can't click on `JButton(s)`.
I add `JDesktopPane` to my `JFrame` in this way:

```
jDesktopPane1 = new JDesktopPane();
jDesktopPane1.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
jDesktopPane1.setOpaque(false);
```

How can i disable `JDesktopPane` when i don't need to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you have to check

1. [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html)
2. [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/)